# Content Security Policy jQuery error using form listener in included file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm getting a variety of CSP errors like the following:

```
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
```

What I'm trying to do:
Use a jQuery listener on dropdown form fields to dynamically change what's being seen next to the form.

**form.php**

```
<form>
  <!-- START Sport -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="selectSport">SPORT</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectSport" name="selectSport">
      <option value="baseball">Baseball</option>
      <option value="basketball">Basketball</option>
      <option value="football">Football</option>
      <option value="hockey">Hockey</option>
      <option value="soccer">Soccer</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- END Sport -->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<!-- END Button -->
</form>

<!-- Form listener -->
<script>
  $('#selectSport').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
</script>
```

This file is included in a wrapper file (because the form is going to be included in a few different pages):

**app.php**

```
<body>
  ...
  <div>
    <?php include ('./app/form.php')?>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

The issue seems to be how the files are structured.  If I put the form and jQuery into app.php, there's no issue.  I'm on a shared hosting server, so I cannot edit the CSP policy.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure jQuery in included before your inline script tag?

Comment: uff.  that's it.  thanks, and sorry to take your time on such a goof!